# Extract values from user-made procedures

Tags: procedural-programming

I've been programming in Mathematica recently, and I'm stuck in the following problem:

I define the following procedure

```
foo1[a_, b_, c_] :=
 Module[{res},
  If[a != 0, {res} = Values[Solve[a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0, x]], 
   res = -c/b];
  Return[res]
 ]

foo2[list_, v_] :=
 Module[{sol, Sol = {}},
  For[i = 1, i <= 3, 
   i++, (sol = i*foo1[list]; Print[AppendTo[Sol, sol]])];
  Sol
 ]

foo2[{1, 2, 3}, 4]
```

First procedure works perfectly; but the second does not evaluate as I want to.

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I'm learning to program in Mathematica, so I'll appreciate the feedback on the problem and the code.

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**: I modified the code so it's cleaner and easy to see what's going on and BAM! I realized I'm asking foo1 to process a list, but it's not defined to do so.

**Is there a command to 'convert' somehow the whole list to several singletons,** if you know what I mean? In other words, is there a command to 'forget' the external braces?

(Thanks to Yves for suggesting breaking down the problem, now I can see a priori what's wrong! (-: )

Comment: Have you tried breaking down the problem? Someone may feel like reverse-engineering / debugging your code,  but your chances are better the the more you reduce the overhead.

Comment: @YvesKlett I'll try to break it down. Just give me some time to think of a more simple exposition of the problem :)

Comment: @YvesKlett Ok, I modified the body, realized something and edited the main question. Now it's clearer what I want!

Comment: You defined `foo1` to take 3 arguments but you are calling it (in foo2) with a single list argument. `foo1[a, b, c]` is not the same as `foo1[{a, b, c}]`

Comment: The command to "forget the braces" is called `Apply`, shorthand `@@`, as in `foo1 @@ {a, b, c} == foo1[a, b, c]`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thank you. Though I oversimplified my original problem, knowing this is still useful for the future. I'll proceed to create another post with my original question... :)

Comment: Wraakvol, a belated welcome! Hope you will enjoy your stay ;-). Glad that you managed to solve your problem. This question may be closed, but that is nothing personal and should not discourage you to post new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to drop the side effect of printing the accumulating result at each step, which is very expensive, your code can be much simplified and will run much faster. What I'm going to show you is how to rewrite your code in the functional style, which is more idiomatic to *Mathematica* than the procedural style you are using.

```
foo1[{0, b_, c_}] := {-c/b}
foo1[{a_, b_, c_}] := Flatten[Values[Solve[a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0, x]]]

foo2[list_List, v_Integer] := With[{r = foo1[list]}, # r & /@ Range[v]]
```

With these much more concise definitions, you would see

```
foo2[{1, 2, 3}, 4]
```

> `{{-1 - I Sqrt[2], -1 + I Sqrt[2]}, 
>   {2 (-1 - I Sqrt[2]), 2 (-1 + I Sqrt[2])},
>   {3 (-1 - I Sqrt[2]), 3 (-1 + I Sqrt[2])},
>   {4 (-1 - I Sqrt[2]), 4 (-1 + I Sqrt[2])}}`

```
foo2[{1, -2, 1}, 4]
```

> `{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}`

```
foo2[{0, 2, -1}, 4]
```

> `{{1/2}, {1}, {3/2}, {2}}`

Some points to note.

- Because *Mathematica* uses its powerful pattern matching capability to match actual arguments to formal argument, it is possible to write `foo1` as two very small one-line definitions and the leave the destructuring of the list of passed-in and the binding of the list elements to the appropriate variable to the evaluator. This lets you pass a list to `foo1` but still have it act as if it were a function of three variables. It also eliminates the need for a call to `If` to handle the special case of where function variable `a` is bound to zero.
- `foo1` is only called once in `foo2`, not at each step as in your code, giving a major improvement in performance.
- It is impossible to print the accumulation of the result list because this functional code doesn't accumulate the elements in the result list on a step-by-step basis; it works across the list structure as a whole. That is a hallmark of the functional style and a source of its power.
- To see how `foo` evaluates, rather than inserting calls to `Print`, use [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html). In the case of `foo2[{1, -2, 1}, 4]`, you will see

  [image: trace]
- To better understand some of the short form notation used in the above code read the articles on [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) and [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) in the documentation.